# XAML previewer on visual studio error message

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Good day, I recently started with iOS development and i set up a macincloud server as my host machine is windows. I installed Xamarin Forms dependencies and it seems to have set up my visual studio sort of properly. With a storyboard application, my previewer works fine, but when I want to create a Xamarin Forms application I get the following error message:

> Your iOS application project must reference the Xamarin.Forms nuget in order to use the previewer.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGYTb.png)
My Main.xaml file shows no errors either.
Here is a screenshot of my references:
[Reference List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPbQQ.png)

I am using visual studio 2017

All help will be highly appreciated

Comment: As the error message suggests, did you try adding reference of Xamarin.Forms nuget?

Comment: I tried to, but I did not find anything on the internet to help me do that. I have the following under my reference list - Analyzers, App5, System, System.Core, System.xml and Xamarin.iOS

Comment: App5 is your iOS applicaiton project?

Comment: Yes, I was testing it out to create a sample app so I kept it the default name when creating the project.

Comment: Are you sure this a Xamarin forms project and not a native Xamarin iOS project instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing Xamarin.Forms reference. In order to add the reference please follow these steps:

1. Right click on your project from solution explorer and click Manage Nuget Packages.
2. Go to Browse tab and search 'xamarin.forms'
3. Install the xamarin.forms reference.

[image]

I hope this would help.

Comment: Thank you, but I do have the xamarin.forms installed from the solution explorer, but I still get the error message

Comment: App5 project includes that reference but the other project of which you shared the screenshot ("screenshot of my references") doesn't include direct reference to Xamarin.Forms. Can you add direct reference of Xamarin.Forms in project of which reference list you shared above?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I managed to fix it, by adding what you said and re-building the solution. However, when I run the simulator it doesn't show the "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms" text, it only displays a blue screen.

Comment: Glad it helped you somewhat. Regarding blue screen, I can't say much as I don't have Xamarin environment setup. Initially I see the missing reference issue so I post the answer.